# Handling of ProgressBar in each row in a ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-progressbar

I have a list of music files, each has its own ProgressBar and a Button to Play/Pause it.

This is my layout of row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Play/Pause" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to update the ProgressBar as the music file progresses every second. and as the music ends update the ProgressBar to 0.

Now the problem is how to handle all this stuff in ArrayAdapter, and How can this be accomplished efficiently.

Should I use notifyDataSetChanged() method of ArrayAdapter class or should I use a thread to update the ProgressBar.

Thanks